# ggplot2 fill not converting ggplotly color mapping correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I'm trying to convert a ggplot2 image using `ggplotly()`, but it's not converting correctly. My ggplot image takes in two lines all of the time, and has a color variable for the `geom_line` component and a fill variable for the `geom_point` component.

Here is my code for the strictly the basic ggplot part:

```
test_data1 = data.frame(
  filter = "Filter 1",
  time = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-03-01"), "days"),
  ovr_perc = rnorm(n = 60, mean = 8, sd = 2),
  neg_perc = rnorm(n = 60, mean = 6, sd = 2),
  count = sample(50:250,60,replace=T)
)

test_data2 = data.frame(
  filter = "Filter 2",
  time = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-03-01"), "days"),
  ovr_perc = rnorm(n = 60, mean = 20, sd = 6),
  neg_perc = rnorm(n = 60, mean = 6, sd = 2),
  count = sample(50:250,60,replace=T)
)

test_data = rbind(test_data1, test_data2)

p = ggplot(test_data, aes(x=time, y=ovr_perc, group = factor(filter)))  +
  geom_line(aes(color=factor(filter))) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=neg_perc, size = count), shape=21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "darkgreen", mid = "yellow", high = "red1", 
                       midpoint = 5, limits = c(0, 10), oob = squish) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("pink", "green")) +
  theme_classic() 
p
```

The image should look something like this, which is almost exactly how I want it to look:

[image]

However, when I try adding the `ggplotly` code to get the tooltip feature, it turns into this:

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

The entire color scheme on each of the points is gone. How can I change this so it keeps the same color scale from the ggplot image to the ggplotly image?

Comment: Possibly related to this [open bug report](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1234).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the open bug report linked above, `geom_point`'s aesthetic mapping for `fill` doesn't work properly, while `color` works fine. According to the bug report, the problem goes away in the package's dev version, but if you don't have easy access to that (neither do I), the following works, at least on my end:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

p2 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x=time, y=ovr_perc, linetype = filter))  +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(filter == "Filter 1"),
            colour = "pink") +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(filter == "Filter 2"),
            colour = "green") +
  geom_point(aes(color = neg_perc, size = count)) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "darkgreen", mid = "yellow", high = "red1", 
                       midpoint = 5, limits = c(0, 10), oob = squish) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid"),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                          color = c("pink", "green")
                        ))) +
  theme_classic(); p2

ggplotly(p2)
```

Explanations:

1. This uses `color` rather than `fill` for `geom_point`, which works fine.
2. The lines are plotted in separate `geom_line` layers, with their colours specified directly, outside `aes()`.
3. The lines' linetype is mapped inside `aes()`, to force the creation of a legend for each filter value, while the actual mapping specified in `scale_linetype_manual` sets both lines to be solid.

[image: ggplotly result]

Comment: That worked for me as well! Thanks for the explanation @Z.Lin!